# Unexpected token error with material-ui example

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a `reactjs` web application using [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) as my base. Everything worked fine. I then added `material-ui` through `npm'. I added an appbar and a couple buttons and everything looked good.

I then tried to add a [popover](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/popover) using an example straight off of `material-ui`'s website and got the following error: "`Unexpected token =`". It's coming from the first `=` after `handleTouchTap`.

Here is the example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Popover from 'material-ui/Popover';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

export default class PopoverExampleSimple extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
  }

  handleTouchTap = (event) => {
    // This prevents ghost click.
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      open: true,
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
    });
  };

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
          label="Click me"
        />
        <Popover
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}}
          targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        >
          <Menu>
            <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Help &amp; feedback" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Settings" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
          </Menu>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you use tool to transform your es6 code to es5? (like babel)

Answer (score 1):

```
handleTouchTap = (event) => {
  ...
};
```

Is a class property (http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which is not supported by default. You can enable it with `babel-preset-stage-1`

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-1`

```
// .babelrc 
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"],
}
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me .. Plus, which .babelrc file is supposed to be modified ?